# Has anyone gotten SD Gundam Capsule Fighter to run on Linux?

Tags: wine, sd-gundam-capsule-fighter

My current setup is running Wine version 1.4.1 on Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail. Most of the games I've installed via wine worked well on 13.04. I am able to download the OG Planet Game Launcher and it seems to run fine on Wine. Then I click the link from the launcher that downloads SD Gundam Capsule Fighter. It's a 3.1mb file named `SDGO_130212.exe`. Clearly this file is too small to be the game. Running the file with Wine does absolutely nothing.

Has any one gotten this game to work via Wine? Is there an alternative download where I can download the full version of the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installer uses Pando Media Booster and suffers from Wine bug 22152 -> http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22152

Start the installer as follows:

$ GC_DONT_GC=1 wine ./SDGO_130212.exe

I also advise to use a newer Wine version from 1.5.x branch (check with your distro/google how to get it).
1.4.1 (stable) is very old.

Regards

Comment: thanx man, I was about to give up on it!